# Search form in Symfony 5 with like parameter does not return results

Tags: forms, symfony, search

I am trying to return only the results from a search form but the function returns 0 results.
I don't get any errors but my results are missing and after days of searching I still don't get what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

I want to type in the form a parameter and return the results after I hit the submit button.

Here is the repository function:

```
public function findAllWithSearch(?string $cont)
    {
        return $this->_em->getConnection()->executeQuery(
            "select cont from account_links al 
                where  al.cont like :cont
                ",['cont'=>'%"' .$cont . '"%']
        )->fetchAllAssociative();
    }
```

Here is the controller function:

```
public function searchAction(Request $request,AccountLinksRepository $repository)
    {
        $searchForm=$this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('cont')
            ->add('search',SubmitType::class)
            ->getForm();
        $searchForm->handleRequest($request);
        if($searchForm->isSubmitted() && $searchForm>isValid()){

             $data = $searchForm->getData();
             $cont = $data['cont'];

             $links = $repository->findAllWithSearch($cont);

             return $this->render('account_links/search.html.twig', [
                 'account_links' => $links]);

        }

        return $this->render('account_links/index.html.twig',[
            'form'=>$searchForm->createView(),

        ]);
    }
```

In `search.html.twig`:

```
<form>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text"
           name="q"
           class="form-control"
           placeholder="Search..."
    >
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button type="submit"
                class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
            <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

and in `index.html.twig`:

```
{% for account_link in account_links %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ account_link.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ account_link.subscriber }}</td>
        <td>{{ account_link.cont }}</td>
        <td>{{ account_link.client }}</td>
        <td>{{ account_link.relationshipType }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Look like your twig is in wrong position (reversed)
2. If you define form manually in twig you don't need to use `createFormBuilder`
3. Avoid to use sql query string like `select * from account_links`

Repository

```
public function findAllWithSearch(?string $cont)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
            ->andWhere('d.cont like :val')
            ->setParameter('val', '%'.$value.'%')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
```

Controller

```
public function searchAction(Request $request,AccountLinksRepository $repository)
    {
         if('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {

             
             $search = $request->request->get('q');

             $links = $repository->findAllWithSearch($cont);

             return $this->render('account_links/search.html.twig', [
                 'account_links' => $links
             ]);

         }

         return $this->render('account_links/index.html.twig',[
             'form'=>$searchForm->createView(),

         ]);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)